# infinite loop when bash call Go program input

Tags: go, sh

I wrote a bash script to automate download my Go program and install to my linux machine. I can via the curl to download but when my Go program prompt the user input, it go to infinite loop. The error shows EOF error.

Do anyone have any idea about it?

Install.sh

```sh
#!/bin/bash
set -e
set -o noglob

curl https://coderkk.net/ReadInput -o ReadInput
chmod a+x ReadInput
./ReadInput
```

ReadInput.go

```golang
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    var text string

    reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    for {
        fmt.Print("Please enter you name here : ")
        text, _ = reader.ReadString('\n')
        text = strings.Replace(text, "\n", "", -1)
        if text != "" {
            break
        }
    }

    fmt.Printf("Hi %s\n", text)
}
```

Comment: I am not sure that I want to pipe some unknown script from an untrusted website into sh...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not related to `Go` - although you shouldn't ignore any potential errors from `reader.ReadString` - it is due to how you are invoking your downloaded script.

The pipe takes the output of curl and turns that into the `stdin` for `sh`. This is fine but your script requires `stdin` from the terminal - which is now lost.

Change your invocation method to something like this:

```
sh -c "$(curl -sfL https://coderkk.net/install.sh)"
```

this will pass the contents of your script to the `sh` interpreter but preserve the user's terminal `stdin`.